# setting value of thymeleaf from field which have 1:N relationship. What should I do?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

The relationship between classes is 1:N. In Thymeleaf, I created a split form object to submit form data. But when I press send, it sends, but I don't see any data on the screen.

Professor.class

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "professor")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString(of = {"id", "username", "userid", "position", "sal", "hiredate"})
public class Professor {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "profno", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String userid;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String position;

    private int sal;

    private String hiredate;

    private int comm;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "deptno")
    private Department department;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "professor")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public Professor(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Professor(String username, String position) {
        this.username = username;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Professor(String username, String position, int sal, String hiredate, int comm, String userid, Department department) {
        this.username = username;
        this.hiredate = hiredate;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.sal = sal;
        this.comm = comm;
        this.position = position;
        if (department != null) {
            setDepartment(department);
        }
    }

    // ===== Method ===== //
    public void setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
        department.getProfessors().add(this);
    }
```

Department.class

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "department")
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@ToString(of = {"id", "name", "loc"})
public class Department {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "deptno", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "dname", length = 100)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 100)
    private String loc;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Professor> professors = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Department(String name, String loc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.loc = loc;
    }
}
```

ProfessorForm.class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProfessorForm {

    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty()
    private String username;
    private String userid;
    private String position;
    private String hiredate;
    private int sal;
    private int comm;
    private Department department;
}
```

Controller.class

```java
Professor professor = new Professor(form.getUsername(), form.getUserid(),
                form.getComm(), form.getHiredate(), form.getSal(), form.getPosition(), form.getDepartment());
```

Thymeleaf

```html
    <form th:action="@{/professor/add}" th:object="${professorForm}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="username">name</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="userid">id</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{userid}" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="position">position</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{position}" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="sal">sal</label>
            <input type="number" th:field="*{sal}" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="hiredate">hiredate</label>
            <input type="date" th:field="*{hiredate}" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="comm">comm</label>
            <input type="range" th:field="*{comm}" class="form-control" min="0" max="100" value="0" placeholder="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label th:for="departmentId">loc</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{department.loc}" class="form-control" placeholder="">
        </div>
```

At the end, it is confirmed that department.loc is the problem. How should we deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to user of the HTML form to select a certain department for the to-be-created professor entity. The easiest way to support this is adding a HTML select that shows all possible departments, allowing the user to select one.

To make this possible with Thymeleaf, you need the following:

1. Update `ProfessorForm` to use the primary key of the entity that should be referenced (`Department` in this case, so use `long`):

```
public class ProfessorForm {

   // instead of: private Department department;
    private long departmentId;
}
```

2. in the `@GetMapping` controller method, return all department names and id's. This is needed to fill up the HTML select

```
List<DepartmentNameAndId> departments = ...
model.addAttribute( "departments", departments);
```

3. Update the Thymeleaf template to use a HTML select:

```
<select th:field="*{departmentId}">
            <option th:each="department : ${departments}"
                    th:text="${department.name}"
                    th:value="${department.id}">
        </select>
```

4. In de `@PostMapping` in the controller, use the `departmentId` to get the corresponding `Department` object and use that to create the `Professor` object.

See [Using HTML select options with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/16/using-html-select-options-with-thymeleaf/) for some more details.

Comment: Thansk for your reply. I have a question. Why not `List<Department> departments = ...` instead of `List<DepartmentNameAndId> departments = ... ?`

Comment: That is also possible, but you only need the name and id for the HTML select, so you could optimize the database query by using a JPA projection that only returns the name and id. But you are right, you can also fetch the full entities.

Comment: understand.  I didn't think of query optimization.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this.

Department.class

```java
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = EAGER)
private List<Professor> professors = new ArrayList<>();
```

ProfessorForm.class

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProfessorForm {

    ...
    private Department departmentId;
```

Controller.class

```java
@GetMapping("/add")
public String addForm(Model model) {

    List<Department> departments = departmentService.findAll();

    model.addAttribute("professorForm", new ProfessorForm());
    model.addAttribute("departments", departments);
    return "professor/add";
}


@PostMapping("/add")
public String add(@Valid ProfessorForm form, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "professor/add";
    }

    Professor professor = new Professor(form.getUsername(), form.getPosition(), form.getSal(), form.getHiredate(),
                form.getComm(), form.getUserid(), form.getDepartmentId());

        professorService.join(professor);

        return "redirect:/professor/list";
}
```

Fixed by `Lazy -> Eager` in `OneToMany`